# Узнать отображается ли элемент через XPath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

У меня есть 2 одинаковые кнопки "OK", в один момент времени отображаетрся одна, а  в другой момент времени другая. При помощи Selenium я могу найти ту самую, отображающуюся, кнопку:

```
[x for x in  browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='MyButton' and @value='OK']") if x.is_displayed()][0].click()
```

Вопрос: можно ли найти кнопку, которая отображается методами XPath?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно у неотображающейся кнопки будет другой класс, по которому можно будет к ней обратиться, либо  свойство style="display: none"

Answer (score 0):

У неотображающихся кнопок обычно свойства отличаются от отображающихся, поэтому в xpath стоит именно на эти свойства и ставить акцент.

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, пример?

Comment: Rонкретный пример пока не найду, но обращайте внимание на следующие элементы: visibility = hidden
display = none
opacity = 0
hight = 0 
width = 0
attribute type = hidden